# How to fix my database to work with 2.5?

Tags: mysql, joomla

I upgraded to Joomla to 3.1 but it broke my site. So I restored from a backup, but turns out my database backup did not work. So now I have a 3.1 database and 2.5 site. How do I fix it? I am not very good with mySQL.

Comment: I would work on figuring out why it broke your site. 
You'd have to go through each sql file in the com_admin/sql folder and reverse the steps. I really don't know if it is possible.  Did you go to the database tab and check for database errors in the 3.1 site?

Comment: I went to the database tab and here is what it says  Table 'on435_content' does not have column 'title_alias' with type 'VARCHAR(255)'. (From file 1.7.3-2011-10-15.sql.)
Table 'on435_content' does not have column 'title_alias' with type 'VARCHAR(255)'. (From file 1.7.4-2011-11-23.sql.)

Comment: Try putting the site on a localhost and upgrading to Joomla 3.1 via the backend again and if that fails, seeing as your database is already based on Joomla 3.1, try downloading a fresh copy of Joomla 3.1.5, place the zip file in the root of your site and extract it. see what the outcome is

Comment: 3.1.5 needs mysql 5.1. Mysql on my Godaddy server is on 5.0.96. So It wont work